# Oracle Partition Interval by day - wrong high value?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I created a table with the following partition interval:

```
create table 
pos_data_two ( 
    start_date        TIMESTAMP,
    store_id          NUMBER,
    inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
    qty_sold          NUMBER(3)
 ) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
 INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'DAY')) 
 (  
  PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('30.10.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
 );
```

When I insert a a row with the timestamp value

```
'31.10.2013 00:00:00'
```

The high value of the new created partition is:

```
TIMESTAMP' 2013-11-01 00:00:00'
```

Is that correct? Shouldn't it be 2013-10-31 00:00:00 ??

Comment: I assume you mean "Shouldn't it be 2013-10-31 00:00:00" (October 31st instead of 1st), right?

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I'm just guessing here)

You're partitioning by days, so values for a given date fall into the same partition.

The row you're inserting has a start_date that's exactly at midnight, so Oracle has to decide whether to put it onto the previous day or onto the next day.

Apparently, Oracle is using the rule

`lower_bound <= value < upper_bound`

to decide which interval a value should go into, so your value

`2013-10-31 00:00:00`

goes into the interval

`[2013-10-31 00:00:00; 2013-11-01 00:00:00 [`

Comment: Why do you want to change the behaviour of the database regarding this?

Comment: true, changing it would make no sense longterm